# C# - Exception on ObservableCollection<>.Add()

Tags: c#, exception, data-binding

I'm a beginner in Binding logic and I'm following the [ListView Data Sources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding/).

I adapted the tutorial to my use, however, I got an exception for the WinPhone:
**`When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to get the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object.`** The problem is I don't use any DateTime object... Android throws another exception which is **`System.FormatException: One of the identified items was in an invalid format.`** I though that my variable in my DataTemplated object `Duration` was the cause of it, but I renamed it and it's finally not the cause of this exception... So what's is happening?

I'm trying to make the following view, however I didn't put de map part in the code because I'm only trying to make my list.

[image]

To make this, I have the three following files:

**Page.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ListeCourses : ContentPage
{
    public ListeCourses()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        initList();
    }

    ObservableCollection<Course> courses = new ObservableCollection<Course>();
    private void initList()
    {
        ListViewCourses.ItemsSource = courses;

        courses.Add(new Course { _Ride = "Caen - Narbonne", _Since = "6 mins", _Duration = "15 mins", _Pseudo = "Simca", _StopNumber = "1" });
        courses.Add(new Course { _Ride = "Le Mans - Ruaudin", _Since = "8 mins", _Duration = "8 mins", _Pseudo = "Sixela05", _StopNumber = "2" });
        courses.Add(new Course { _Ride = "Rennes - Epitech", _Since = "3 mins", _Duration = "11mins", _Pseudo = "Emixam23", _StopNumber = "1" });
    }
}
```

**page.xaml** `// Each item shown on the image above have another design that just a Label, but it's not the problem at the moment, so I didn't put the final design to focus the main problem.`

```
<ContentPage.Content>
<ListView x:Name="ListViewCourses">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <!--Custom course cell-->
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="50dp" />
          <RowDefinition Height="50dp" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
          <!-- Top grid -->
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

          <Label Text="{Binding _Ride}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding _Since}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>

        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
          <!-- Bottom grid -->
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Label Text="{Binding _Duration}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <Label Text="{Binding _Pseudo}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Text="{Binding _StopNumber}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
        <Button x:Name="More" Text="+" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
        <Button x:Name="Agree" Text="V" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4"/>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**Course.cs**

```
public class Course
{
    public string _Ride { get; set; }
    public string _Since { get; set; }
    public string _Duration { get; set; }
    public string _Pseudo { get; set; }
    public string _StopNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe it's stupid, but in the **TAGs Section** when I'm creating this question, Stackoverflow's suggesting me `datetime` TAG... Does I really miss something?

Thank for help !

**Call Stack**
**[External Code]**

> Project.ni.DLL!Project.Controlers.Driver.ListeCourses.initList() Line 20    C#
>       Project.ni.DLL!Project.Controlers.Driver.ListeCourses.ListeCourses() Line 12    C#
>       Project.ni.DLL!Project.App.App() Line 12    C#
>       Project.WinPhone.ni.EXE!Project.WinPhone.MainPage.MainPage() Line 18    C#
>       [External Code] 
>       Project.WinPhone.ni.EXE!Project.WinPhone.App.OnLaunched(Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) Line 96 C#

Comment: None of this code seems to be related to the actual issue.

Comment: That's what I think, so what's happening? It breaks on the first add()..

Comment: I would be interested to see the stack trace. Can't you provide that? So please surround the failing code with try catch and read the https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/System.Exception.StackTrace/

Comment: Question edited, check at the end :) I also tried to remove `ListViewCourses.ItemsSource = courses;` and I edited this line `<ListView x:Name="ListViewCourses" ItemsSource="{Binding courses}">`. Now I don't get any exception but the screen stays black :/

Comment: Do you have a DB behind, like SqlLite probably, trying to save the first added item and hence the error? Just guessing.

Comment: The code a put it's a simple try in an empty project, you can test it honestly. It's only a page with a class.

Comment: Maybe you did have a DateTime property and "forgot" to build the project that contains the Course class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114369/discussion-between-emixam23-and-razvanr).